# A confusing question on absorption spectrum

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy

[image: This is the question]

Every solution of this question on the internet seems to indicate the answer is option (3). Their reasoning is that, since X is the ground level and absorption of light occurs in the ground level (when H is not excited), lines 1, 2, and 3 occur in the adsorption spectrum. But if 1, 2 and 3 absorb the incoming light shouldn't the absorption spectrum exclude the incoming light that excites 1, 2 and 3. Shouldn't the answer be option (2); if not, can you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atoms spend most of their time in the ground state. So if a 1, 2, or 3 photon passes by, the atom is ready to absorb it. But it isn't ready for 4, 5, or 6.

On the other hand, if an atom is ready to emit a photon, it is excited. Many processes that excite an atom can excite it to any state. So all of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 are likely to be emitted.

Comment: So if the H atom is at the ground state then the adsorption spectrum will have dark bands in the region of 1, 2 and 3. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

If the atom absorbs light to make the inverse of transitions 1, 2, or 3, then it will be in state C, B, or A at least briefly.  While it's in any of those states it can absorb another photon to make the transitions AB, AC or BC; so *very* weak absorption lines should exist corresponding to 5, 4, and 6 if the light is intense enough that there is a reasonable probability of photons of the right energies arriving at the right times.  However, in a typical absorption spectrometer the intensity is low enough that the probability is negligible.